# Enviar imagenes por formularios reactivos angular

Tags: angular

Tengo que enviar una imágen en un formulario junto con más datos, este es el código:

El formulario reactivo:

```
        this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        dni: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('^(([A-Z]\\d{8})|(\\d{8}[A-Z]))$')
        ]],
        name: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(64)
        ]],
        surname: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(64)
        ]],
        email: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            CustomValidators.email,
            Validators.maxLength(64)
        ]],
        city: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(32)
        ]],
        phone: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$'),
            Validators.maxLength(9),
            Validators.minLength(9)
        ]],
        postal_code: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('^(?:0[1-9]|[1-4]\\d|5[0-2])\\d{3}$')
        ]],
        avatar: null
    });
```

La función que añade la imagen al formulario:

```
    onFileChange(event) {
    if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        this.editForm.get('avatar').setValue(file);
    }
}
```

Y se lo envío a mi servicio de esta manera:

```
                if (response.value) {
                return this.authService.editProfileUserAuth(this.editForm.value, this.user.id).subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        this.toastr.success(response['message'], 'Enhorabuena');
                        this.getProfileUserAuth();
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        this.toastr.error(error, 'Error');
                    }
                );
            }
```

Bien, cuando llega a mi servicio obtengo esto en un consolelog:

```
dni: "9858579X" name: "Test"surname: "Test"email: "Test"city: "Test"phone: "999999999"postal_code: "000000"avatar: File {name: "default-avatar.png", lastModified: 1581014601466, lastModifiedDate: Thu Feb 06 2020 19:43:21 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 48598, …}
```

Así podría trabarlo correctamente pero cuando lo envío a mi api de esta manera:

```
    editProfileUserAuth(userForm, id) {
    console.log(userForm);
    return this.http.put(
        `${routes.API_ENDPOINT_USER}/${id}`,
        userForm,
    ).pipe(map(data => data));

}
```

Esto es lo que envia en las cabeceras:

```
dni: "9858579X"
name: "Test"
surname: "Test"
email: "Test"
city: "Test"
phone: "999999999"
postal_code: "00000"
avatar: {}
```

No sé por qué viene el objeto avatar vacío ¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Si ejecuta en un console.log el valor de tu FormControl

```js
console.log(this.editForm.get('avatar').value);
```

Podrás observar que solo te trae el nombre, la forma que veo como lo puedes hacer es transformar la imagen a base64 y trabajar con la imagen de esa forma, puedo sugerirte hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-img-fomrs-reactive',
  templateUrl: './img-fomrs-reactive.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./img-fomrs-reactive.component.css']
})
export class ImgFomrsReactiveComponent implements OnInit {

  editForm: FormGroup;
  formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
   }

  private initForm() {
    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dni: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^(([A-Z]\\d{8})|(\\d{8}[A-Z]))$')
      ]],
      name: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(64)
      ]],
      surname: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(64)
      ]],
      city: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(32)
      ]],
      phone: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$'),
        Validators.maxLength(9),
        Validators.minLength(9)
      ]],
      postal_code: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^(?:0[1-9]|[1-4]\\d|5[0-2])\\d{3}$')
      ]],
      avatar: null
    });

    this.editForm.get('avatar').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if (value !== null && value !== '') {
        this.imgToBase64((document.querySelector('input[type="file"]') as HTMLInputElement).files[0]);
      }
    });
  }

  private imgToBase64(file: any) {
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = this.toBase64.bind(this);
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  }

  toBase64(e) {
    console.log('data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(e.target.result));
  }
}
```

**En el metodo toBase64(e) ya queda la img transformada a base64.**

Answer (score 0):

tienes que enviar tipo de 'formData', porque lo que estás enviando es 'application/json'.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
// Haces lo mismo con append de todos tus variables que quieres enviar
formData.append('avatar', this.editForm.get('avatar').value);

return this.authService.editProfileUserAuth(formData, this.user.id).subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        this.toastr.success(response['message'], 'Enhorabuena');
                        this.getProfileUserAuth();
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        this.toastr.error(error, 'Error');
                    }
                );
```